# If derivative of $f$ is continuous, then $f$ is continuous.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

I have searched a lot, but i haven't found any proof about that statement. I have checked the proof of

> If $f$ is differentiable, then $f$ is continuous

but it's not the same argument I think. Also, I want to know what's your opinion about the statement

> If derivative of $f$ is not continuous, then $f$ is not continuous

Comment: Continuous at R or at domain of a function ?

Comment: 1. Continuous at R
2. Continuous at a spesific point x0.

Comment: "what's your opinion ..." Math isn't about opinions.

Comment: "*If a car is red, then it is a vehicle.*"

Comment: @JohnColeman It is not about, however there is room for them. How about open problems?

Comment: @TStancek Surely there is room in mathematics for epistemic states which fall short of certainty, including thoughts about the truth values of open problems. Using the word "opinion" for such things would often seem awkward. Few mathematicians would say something like "It's my opinion that P isn't NP" but would instead say something more like "I strongly suspect that P isn't NP." Opinions in the more idiomatic sense would be for things like the importance of fuzzy logic or whether or not the epsilon-delta definition of limits should be used in calc one.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

If $f$ is differentiable, then $f$ is continuous. The continuity of $f'$ is irrelevant here.

In particular, *even if $f'$ is discontinuous, $f$ is continuous*.

Comment: Note: the abovewritten is true if we're not taking generalized functions into account

Answer (score 17):

Your problem seems to be the logical relationships between the statements

1. *If f is differentiable, then it is continuous*
2. *If the derivative of $f$ is continuous, then $f$ is continuous*
3. *If the derivative of $f$ is not continuous, then $f$ is not continous*.

The first statement trivially implies the second, since saying "the derivative of $f$ is continuous" is the same as saying "$f$ is differentiable *and* $f^{\prime}$ is continuous".

The contrapositive of the third statement is "If $f$ is continuous, then the derivative of $f$ is continuous." This is false. For example, the function 
$$f(x)=x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$
is differentiable everywhere, with derivative
$$f^{\prime}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
2x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)& x\neq 0
\\
0 & x=0
\end{array}\right.$$
But $\lim_{x\to 0}f^{\prime}(x)$ does not exist, hence $f^{\prime}$ is not continuous.

Answer (score 3):

$f'$ need not be continuous.

Suppose that $f'(x)$ exists in the interval $(a,b)$. If $\xi \in (a,b)$, then $f'(\xi)$ exists. Hence $f$ is continuous at $\xi$. Since this is true for all $\xi$ in $(a,b)$, then $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$.

Comment: Sorry. It should have said $f'$ need not be continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Answering only part of the question: "If derivative of f is not continuous, then f is not continuous": As perhaps the simplest counter-example, the absolute value function is continuous but not continuously differentiable.

This does not disprove the opposite statement, of course.