# I need to know about continuity and differentiability

Tags: integration, derivatives, continuity

> So our instructor has given a question to find if $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) dt $. He asked us if $F(x)$ is differentiable.

I know about the continuity and differentiability test, but my question is that  should I apply the test on $f(t)$? Which tests to apply? if I only apply continuity on $f(t)$, and say it is continuous, does it mean $F(x)$ is continuous too? Do I have to do a differentiability test on $f(t)$ as well, or just continuity is okay?

Thanks

Comment: $F(x) = \int f(t)\,dx$ is probably not what you mean to write

Comment: I am sorry yes, it should be $dt$

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Formal_statements This should be helpful

Comment: @Academic Thanks! SO does it mean that I will only check for continuity of f(t), and if it is continuous, F(x) will be continuous **and** differentiable? SO I don't need to look for f(t)'s differentiability?

Comment: Please try to focus you questions, there are so many that it is difficult to properly address them.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

$
\begin{gather*} 
F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt\\
\therefore F'(x) = f(x)\\
\end{gather*}
$

Now if $f(x)$ is continuous and differenciable then $\implies$$F'(x)$ is also continuous and differenciable.

Now for $F'(x)$ to be continuous and differenciable, $F(x)$ must be continuous and differenciable.

Refer this if you are not familiar with the above statement: [f'(x) and f(x) continuity and differenciability](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2741229/if-derivative-of-f-is-continuous-then-f-is-continuous)

Now if $f(x)$ is continuous and non differenciable then $\implies$$F'(x)$ is also continuous and non differenciable.

Now for $F'(x)$ to be continuous and non differenciable, $F(x)$ must be continuous and differenciable (as $F'(x)$ exists).

So $F(x)$ is both continuous and differenciable, if $f(x)$ is only continuous and need not be differenciable.

Comment: thanks. I just wanna know that do I have to do a differentiability test on f(t)? or only continuity?

Comment: I downvoted because I believe that this answer is of abysmal quality, even for the task at hand. I won't go into the details of explaining why. I won't write an answer of mine either, because I don't want to.

Comment: @XZCY I think the downvote may be there are somethings unclear, but sometime people only downvote without reason and even for correct answer, and I also dont like that. Anyway, it seems that the question should be $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$, it should have some other conditions which are needed to provide.

Comment: @Astudent Sorry there was a flaw in my derivation, f(t) only need to be continuous for F(x) to be differenciable and I have corrected it.

Comment: @Ercanayan we can interchange variable inside the integral and it doesn't affect the rest of the equation, so I replaced t by x.

Comment: @XZCY $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt$, $F(x+h) = \int_a^{x+h} f(t)dt$, the derivative is take
the limit of the diff. and divide by h, there is no need to put $t=x$.

Comment: @Tim ok thanks I didn't realise that..

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the first fundamental theorem of calculus, and you can prove that if $f$ is integrable on an interval containing $c$ and $f$ is continuous at the point $c$, then $F$ is differentiable at $c$.